# How to find the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} n(H(n) - \ln(n) - \gamma)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

How to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(H(n) - \ln(n) - \gamma)$$

where $H(n) = 1  + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$ is  the $n^{th}$ harmonic number and $\gamma$ is the [Euler Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).

Also it is known that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \big(H(n)- \ln(n)\big) = \gamma$.

Comment: Hi, I have edited your question just to make it more readable. Please check if I changed the meaning of your question

Comment: Yeah.. its fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, we have the asymptotic expression
$$H(n) = \log(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} + O(n^{-2}).$$
Therefore
$$n(H(n) - \log(n) - \gamma) = \frac{1}{2} + O(n^{-1}) \to \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Small and to the point ... thank you'

Answer (score 5):

Let
$$u_n=H(n)-\log n-\gamma$$
then we have
$$u_{n+1}-u_n=\frac1{n+1}-\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\=\frac1n\frac1{1+1/n}-\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\sim_\infty \frac1n\left(1-\frac1n\right)-\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}=-\frac1{2n^2}$$
hence we have
$$u_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty (u_k-u_{k+1})\sim_\infty \frac12\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\sim_\infty\frac12\int_n^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2n}$$
hence
$$u_n=\frac{1}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
and finaly
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(H(n) - \ln(n) - \gamma)=\lim_{n\to \infty}nu_n=\frac12 $$

Comment: In your third line u have taken 1/n * 1/(1+1/n) as the expression on the right except the -1/n term which u get from the log expression. Could u please explain how u gt the 1/n *(1-1/n) +1/2n^2 terms... 

Because if u just sum up 1/(n+1) and -1/n(from log term) u get -1/(n^2+n) .Please explain... 
Also how summation of 1/k^2 becomes integration ??